# convert sql query to magento collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, grid, sql

I am having a complex SQL query to make a custom report & showing same to custom report grid but somehow not able to convert the query into Magento's equivalent Collection.

```
SELECT SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) AS `ordered_qty`, `order_items`.`name` AS `order_items_name`, `order_items`.`product_id` AS `entity_id`, `e`.`entity_type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`sku`, `order`.`created_at`, `order`.`updated_at`, `ps`.`qty` AS `current_stock`, (ps.qty - SUM(order_items.qty_ordered)) AS `difrnc`, `c`.`value` as `costing`, ((ps.qty - SUM(order_items.qty_ordered)) * `c`.`value`) AS `totcsttostock` 
         FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_items` 
         INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON `order`.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND `order`.state <> 'canceled' 
         LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON (e.type_id NOT IN ('grouped', 'configurable', 'bundle')) AND e.entity_id = order_items.product_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4 
         LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `ps` ON ps.product_id=order_items.product_id 
         LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `c` ON c.entity_id=order_items.product_id and c.attribute_id=79 
         WHERE `order`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2017-09-22 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-22 23:59:59' and (parent_item_id IS NULL) 
         GROUP BY `order_items`.`product_id` HAVING (SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > 0) ORDER BY `ordered_qty` desc
```

I have converted this much(which might have mistakes), but needed help/suggestion ahead

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setResourceModel('sales/order_item');
    $this->_init('sales/order_item','item_id'); }
public function setDateRange($from, $to) {
$this->_reset();
        $this->getSelect()
             ->joinInner(array('i' => $this->getTable('sales/order_item')),'i.order_id = main_table.entity_id','SUM(i.qty_ordered) AS ordered_qty')
->joinLeft(array('ps' => $this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_item')), 'ps.product_id=i.product_id', 'ps.qty as current_stock, (ps.qty - SUM(i.qty_ordered)) AS difrnc')
->joinLeft(array('e' => $this->getTable('catalog/product')), '(e.type_id NOT IN ("grouped", "configurable", "bundle")) AND e.entity_id = i.product_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4')
->joinLeft(array('c' => $this->getTableName('catalog/product','decimal')), 'c.entity_id=i.product_id and c.attribute_id=79', 'c.value as costing, ((ps.qty - SUM(i.qty_ordered)) * c.value) AS totcsttostock')
             ->where('i.parent_item_id is null')
             ->where("i.created_at BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'")
             ->where('main_table.state = \'complete\'')
             ->columns(array('ordered_qty' => 'count(distinct main_table.entity_id)'));
             echo $this->getSelect();
        return $this;
    }
```

Please, can someone help or suggest anything?

Comment: why not use direct queries ? : https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/

Comment: Thanks @Chester but, If I use direct sql query will I be able to export the report result to csv/xml(by default functionality) from grid - Please have a look on this for getting better idea = https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212342/problem-in-creating-custom-reports-for-inventory-forecasting